# Undefined Index in php (I've searched all over internet, and stackoverflow, tried almost everything)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

`enter code here`this is php code

```
$choice_spc_port = $_POST["txtSpace"];  (THIS LINE GIVES UNDEFINED INDEX NOTICE)
$choice_loc = $_POST["txtLocation"]; (THIS LINE GIVES UNDEFINED INDEX NOTICE)
```

And this is HTML Form

```
<form id="animalform" name="animalform" method="post" action="animalform.php">
<div  class="wrapper"> <strong><span>*</span> Text Space portion:</strong>
            <div class="formText">
              <input type="radio" name="txtSpace" value="HR"/>Text space for Horse.<br />
      <input type="radio" name="txtSpace" value="ZB"/>Text Space For Zebra<br />
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper"> <strong><span>*</span> Animal Location:</strong>
                <div class="formText">
                <input type="radio" name="txtLocation" value="txtSetXY"/> Specify Animal Location<br />
                    <div style="padding-left:20px;">
                    X: <input type="text" id="locField" name="txtXLocation">  <span>Taking (x=1,y=1) top left box. Increment +1 in value of X moving right</span><br />
                    Y: <input type="text" id="locField" name="txtYLocation">  <span>Taking (x=1,y=1) top left box. Increment +1 in value of Y moving downwards</span><br />
                    </div>
                    <input type="radio" name="txtLocation" value="Default"/>Default
                </div>

            </div>
</div>
```

Query to insert in database

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO dbForm (db_space_portion, db_animal_location) VALUES ('{$choice_spc_port}', '{$choice_loc}')";
```

I tried the same in firefox and those two lines give notice as mentioned in bracket. Also on internet many people are looking for solution. So I think this question will help many out there.

Comment: @DevangRathod i edited for the form

Comment: isset method solved the problem.. Thankx guys a lot for answering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query.

```
if(isset($_POST['txtSpace'])) {
    $choice_spc_port = $_POST['txtSpace'];
}
if(isset($_POST['txtLocation'])) {
    $choice_loc = $_POST['txtLocation'];
}

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbForm (db_space_portion, db_animal_location) VALUES ('{$choice_spc_port}', '{$choice_loc}')");
```

Answer (score 1):

This error shows in newer version of PHP.

There are various way to remove the error:

1. You can use error suppress method for this
2. Check that variable is not empty or set it to 0 e.g. `choice_spc_port=0` at the start
3. Isset method also works good

Answer (score 0):

use `isset` for this, it will not give you undefined index notice when the `$_POST['txtSpace']` and `$_POST['txtLocation']` are empty and not set.

```
if(isset($_POST['txtSpace']))
{
     $choice_spc_port = $_POST["txtSpace"];  
}
if(isset($_POST['txtLocation']))
{  
     $choice_loc = $_POST["txtLocation"];
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of this line? if(isset($_POST['txtSpace']))

Comment: @Ashis this line checks that `$_POST['txtSpace']` contains any value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to get any Post variables:

```
if(isset($_POST['txtSpace'])){$choice_spc_port = $_POST["txtSpace"];}
if(isset($_POST['txtLocation'])){$choice_loc = $_POST["txtLocation"];}
```

And to your SQL sentence:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO dbForm (db_space_portion, db_animal_location) VALUES ({'$choice_spc_port'}, {'$choice_loc'})";
```

Comment: how does this different from mine? ({'$choice_spc_port'}

Comment: This is exactly the same but it use to give warnings on previous ie versions